# Factory Girl has_many/has_many through with validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I'm running into problems correctly setting up my factories for a has_many/has_many through or has_and_belongs_to_many association with validations. The client model/factory have been omitted, but it does exist. What is the best way to set up a has_many to has_many through association with validations, where attributes need to be passed in?

I've tried a few methods of getting it to work without success. Current relevant code is below (slightly altered). Other methods tried: after(:create) and before(:create) on client_team to create user_clients, traits on client_teams and user_clients that define the association, using build_list/create_list in place of shovel operator.

ClientTeam model:

```
belongs_to :client
has_many :client_team_rosters
has_many :users, through: :client_team_rosters
```

User model:

```
belongs_to :client
has_many :client_team_rosters
has_many :client_teams, through: :client_team_rosters
validates_presence_of :client_teams
```

ClientTeamRoster model:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :client_team
```

Relevant factories:

```
factory :client_team do
  client
  team_name "stuff"
end

factory :client_team_roster do
  client
  user
end

factory :user do
  ...
  factory :user_client do
    client

    before(:create) do |user_client|
     client_team = user_client.client.client_teams.first
     user_client.client_team_rosters << FactoryGirl.build(:client_team_roster, user: user_client, client_team: client_team)
    end
  end
end
```

Spec file:

```
before(:each) do
  @client = create(:client)
  @client_team = create(:client_team, client: @client)
end

it "should do something" do
  user_client = create(:user_client, client: @client)
end
```

Current error:

```
Validation failed: Client_teams can't be blank
```

Answer (score 1):

Ugh, so right after posting this, I decided to make a small tweak and it ended up working. Instead of deleting the question I'll just post my fix to help others in the future (hopefully with less trial and error)

Within the user_client factory, change the callback to:

```
before(:create) do |user_client|
 client_team = user_client.client.client_teams.first
 user_client.client_teams << client_team
end
```

Which mimics how we set up our models in the codebase otherwise. I could've sworn I gave this a go earlier, but trying it this time around worked out

Edit: We also have a factory that inherits from :user_client. In those cases, the before(:create) doesn't seem to trigger. However these inherited factories can be initialized with :client_teams => [client_team] when creating/building